# Is my iMac running Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I am looking for Mavericks on my iMac. I have looked in Finder but I do not see it there. How can I find out if Mavericks was installed on my iMac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Apple logo:

[image]

Then: click 'About This Mac'

This opens a window with four tabs. The 'overview' tab shows the current system you are running.

[image]

Comment: Except for most OS X versions prior to Yosemite don't refer to the 'name' of the release, just the version: Mavericks being 10.9.x

Answer (score 9):

Go the to the Apple menu (top left) => About this mac.

The existing versions are following :

- OS X 10.10 Yosemite
- OS X 10.9 Mavericks
- OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
- OS X 10.7 Lion

Comment: Very annoying OS naming convention.

Comment: I strongly disagree. People like names not "stupid" numbers.

Comment: I mean, pick one or the other. When one part of the documentation says "You need Yosemite" and the other part says you need "10.10" you can't tell without this table which is which.